# Is there a reliable method to determine CPU temperature?

Tags: cpu, temperature

What I would like to ask may seem something like a duplicate, but - according to my recent searches - it is not.

I have a Pc with ASUS M5A97 EVO R2.0, FX-8320 and GTX960 and I would like to monitor the temperature of these components if possible.

The temperature of the card can be seen in the proprietary nvidia driver, so it is not a problem, but unfortunately i cannot determine the cpu temp. (i have tried with lm-sensors and psensors which showed me 15 °C and values like that). I can only see the actual temperature at UEFI after a restart which is not the most convenient solution I can imagine. Oh, an almost forgot: According to AIDA on windows my cpu can be 5-6 °C hotter under Ubuntu as I have checked it after reboot.

Can you please recommend me some other options?

Thank you!

Comment: `acpi -t`, and `man acpi`

Comment: you can install xsensors `sudo apt install xsensors` http://i.imgur.com/nxcYLch.png

Comment: @MohamedSlama Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately xsensors provided the same false information :(

Comment: None of the above seems to work, unfortunately. To see the differences I've drawn a graph under Windows from the core temp values of aida under the same load and compared it with psensors values. They look almost the same in terms of temperature, but a better way of measurement would be nice but I am afraid it is not possible. :(